# HW: Java program generating NullPointerException error message

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am writing code for my Data Structures class. My code consists of 5 classes that combine to create an array of 100 random integers of value between 0 and 100, pick out various statistical information from those numbers and generate the standard deviation compared to a normal distribution. Apparently, my method for calculating the standard deviation is linked to something the gives a null pointer error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at UnorderedArrayList.standardDeviation(UnorderedArrayList.java:113)
at ValueList.main(ValueList.java:53)
```

The code snippet is

```
IntElement shortList = (IntElement) (this.list[i]);
int num = shortList.getNum();
d = num - average;
var += Math.pow((double) d,(double) 2);
```

the error IDs line 113:

```
int num = shortList.getNum();
```

getNum appears to work fine elsewhere in the program.

I've spent hours working with a private tutor and I've asked my professor for advice, but I can't pin down the cause of this error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite obvious, `this.list[i]` is returning null so you should check the element under this index whether is really set. If you have something like

```
IntElement[] array = new IntElement[100];
array[0] = new IntElement();
```

Then rest of the elements except `array[0]` will be null, so you probably have your index too high.

Answer (score 2):

```
IntElement shortList = (IntElement) (this.list[i]);
int num = shortList.getNum();
```

Here your `shortList` is null which means that the element present at the `i`th position of `list` is null.

Answer (score 1):

I agree to the answers given above, just to add to it, it is always advisable to put a null check before such cases.

```
IntElement shortList = (IntElement) (this.list[i]);
int num = 0; 
if (shortList !=null) {
    num = shortList.getNum();
} else {
    System.out.println("No items returned"); //or log it. 
}
```